# How to input a non string with input() in python

Tags: python, string, input

I want to input a variable using the input() function in python. But it thinks of it as a string so it does not work.

Here is an example code:

```
a = 8
b = input("Enter a number: ")
print(b * b)
```

Here, when you input a it thinks it's a string and cannot perform math operations on it.

So what should I do?

I tried searching on the internet but nothing useful came up.

Comment: cast it as an integer with int(), eg. b = int(input("Enter a number: "))

Comment: you mean int(input("Enter a number: ")) ? it does not work because it converts a non number containing str into int which gives an error

Comment: @Carl What exactly do you input? The string "one" (for example)?

Comment: I want to input the variable a. Also it seems that I kind of made a mistake in my question because if you just use input("Enter a number: ") it wont work if you perform math on it even if you do not use a variable. But I still havent found an answer to my question.

Comment: @Carl, so you want to input "a" and have the input equal to 8?

Comment: Yeah I know I am not inputting an integer because I do not know how to input a variable that equals an integer

Comment: You can't input `a`, or at least, you shouldn't. The *user* has no reason to know anything about what variable names you've used. Your prompt asks for a number, not the name of a variable that references a number.

Comment: You do *not* want to look up variables by their names. You can use a dict: `nums = {'a': 8}`, then use `nums[b]`.

Comment: @chepner Oh okay that answered my question